# How to design keras neuralnet for predicting 2 (+1 not A not B) classes data with 2 classes training

Tags: r, deep-learning, keras

I have a convnet model for binary image classification: cat/dog.

```
library(keras)
conv_base <- application_vgg16(
  weights = "imagenet",
  include_top = FALSE,
  input_shape = c(150, 150, 3)
)

# Hyperparameter construction
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  conv_base %>%
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

model %>% compile(
  loss = "binary_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 2e-5),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)


img <- image_load('test_image.jpg', target_size = c(150, 150))
x <- image_to_array(img)
x <- array_reshape(x, c(1, dim(x)))
preds_class <- model %>% predict_classes(x)
model %>% predict(x)
```

The `predict(x)` give one probability which lets us infer it being
a cat or dog.

I only have training data two classes: cat/dog.
Is there a way I can modify the code at `compile()` or hyperparameter construction 
so that it spit out 3 probabilities for

1. cat
2. dog
3. non_catdog

The third category is everything not in class 1 and 2 (cat/dog)
Strategy to design hyperparameter  or compile for predicting 2 (+1 other) classes data with 2 class training

Comment: Can you confirm the shape of the network? i.e. are you using a sigmoid or softmax output? Sounds like the network is set up as a binary classifier.

Answer (score 6):

I feel your issue may be in the construction of the network:

```
# Hyperparameter construction
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
  conv_base %>%
  layer_flatten() %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>% 
  layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")
```

Your final layer uses a sigmoid activation which squashes your output to `[0,1]`. I think what you are after is a `softmax` activation as you have more than 2 classes.

Not exactly sure on the `keras` syntax but maybe something along the lines of:

```
model <- keras_model_sequential() %>% 
      conv_base %>%
      layer_flatten() %>% 
      layer_dense(units = 256, activation = "relu") %>% 
      layer_dense(units = 3, activation = "softmax")
```

---

As flagged in the comments - the networks loss function will also need to be changed. The binary entropy equation assumes only a single vector of predictions and observations which is not the case in this architecture.

```
model %>% compile(
  loss = "categorical_crossentropy",
  optimizer = optimizer_rmsprop(lr = 2e-5),
  metrics = c("accuracy")
)
```

---

**Update**

You are trying to capture 3 possible outputs. Possibility of belonging to class A, B, or neither. Your label vector should look something like:

```
Class A = [1, 0, 0] 
Class B = [0, 1, 0] 
Class C (! A || B) = [0, 0, 1]
```

It might seem logical to assign class C as `[0, 0]` but that is problematic giving how the 'softmax' works. Each training case is given a probability of belonging to EACH of the classes. Therefore, a training example of Class A could be given a 30% probability of belonging to class B. The class prediction is essentially a vote.

> I.e. I predict that this example is of Class A as it has the highest probability compared to the other class probabilities.

Comment: Should I also change `loss = "binary_crossentropy"` in [keras::compile()](https://keras.rstudio.com/reference/compile.html) into `categorical`. And

Comment: Yes. Binary entropy assumes a single vector of predictions and observations in its equation. As a starting point, change the loss function to `categorical_crossentropy`. I know there are options to choose loss functions on each of the inputs by passing in a dict but in the first instance just use `categorical_crossentropy`. Regards.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure you know I only have 2 classes of training data and not 3. I got this error following your suggestion ` Error when checking model target: expected dense_2 to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (, 1)`

Comment: I've added an additional section highlighting how to structure your training label vector.

Comment: I saw your update. Do you mean that I have to train 3 classes to make it work? You mentioned about `given 30%` probability. How do you implement that?

Comment: Well you want to implement a model which captures the following cases: Class A, Class B, Neither class. You need to treat the 'Neither class' as its own outcome. I.e. three outcomes.

Comment: Did you get this sorted?